# API Permission Failed (7) when activating a Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, subscriber

I am trying to re-activate a subscriber, who I have previously unsubscribed using `LogUnsubEvent` from the 'All Subscribers' list.

[image]

To do this I am trying to update the Subscriber's `Status` field, using the Fuel SDK and PHP:

```
$obj = new ET_Subscriber();
$obj->authStub = $etClient;
// Have also tried SubscriberKey
$obj->props = ['Status' => 'Active', 'EmailAddress' => 'foo@example.com'];
$result = $obj->patch();
```

The result is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsa:Action>UpdateResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:a9733b8e-e87a-43c6-b09d-c594ce3568f5</wsa:MessageID>
      <wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:96226130-a985-4baa-bf8e-efb9a513d757</wsa:RelatesTo>
      <wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-b6608242-90fe-41fe-b715-2621c084f921">
            <wsu:Created>2018-05-10T17:07:56Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2018-05-10T17:12:56Z</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <UpdateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <Results>
            <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
            <StatusMessage>API Permission Failed.</StatusMessage>
            <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
            <ErrorCode>7</ErrorCode>
         </Results>
         <RequestID>2389de99-06c2-40cf-97e2-13aa6b3ea30c</RequestID>
         <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
      </UpdateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As far as I know this API user has the full permissions. It unsubscribes without issue. How should I resubscribe a person?

Fuel SDK's generated request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>*</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce>***</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2018-05-10T17:03:34Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <oAuth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">
            <oAuthToken>***</oAuthToken>
        </oAuth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:UpdateRequest>
            <ns1:Options/>
            <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:Subscriber">
                <ns1:EmailAddress>foo@example.com</ns1:EmailAddress>
                <ns1:Status>Active</ns1:Status>
            </ns1:Objects>
        </ns1:UpdateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by writing my SOAP request by hand in SoapUI and working backwards from there.

Despite a Patch being correct, the PHP Fuel SDK will only do a Patch+Upsert for a Subscriber if you use `put()`.

The working code:

```
$obj = new ET_Subscriber();
$obj->authStub = $etClient;
$obj->props = ['Status' => 'Active', 'SubscriberKey' => '000076Etc22Fake'];
$result = $obj->put();
```

And the SOAP structure that's needed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>*</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">*</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce>***</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2018-05-11T09:20:46Z</wsu:Created>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <oAuth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">
            <oAuthToken>***</oAuthToken>
        </oAuth>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>

    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:UpdateRequest>
            <ns1:Options>
                <ns1:SaveOptions>
                    <ns1:SaveOption>
                        <ns1:PropertyName>*</ns1:PropertyName>
                        <ns1:SaveAction>UpdateAdd</ns1:SaveAction>
                    </ns1:SaveOption>
                </ns1:SaveOptions>
            </ns1:Options>
            <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:Subscriber">
                <ns1:SubscriberKey>000076Etc22Fake</ns1:SubscriberKey>
                <ns1:Status>Active</ns1:Status>
            </ns1:Objects>
        </ns1:UpdateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```